# PHP include w/o echo

Tags: php

I'm coding a web site and I have a php fonction called site_nav.php which first define a $list array and than echos it in a json form.

This way, I can get my web site map with ajax.

My problem is that now, I would like to get the $list object in php, without echoing the json object.

My question: Is there a way to include my php file without activation of the echo call which is in it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just use output buffering. See the documentation on [`ob_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_end_clean`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php).

```
ob_start();
include("file.php");
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use an output buffer to catch the output in a string.

```
ob_start();

include_once('file.php');

var $output = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: This is causing my file to be echoed twice (when I echo $output after setting it like you did). Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind I used `ob_get_clean()` instead to fixed this

Answer (score 3):

You can use output buffering to achieve this.

```
ob_start();
include("myfile.php");
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without a hack. You could use output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "foo";
ob_end_clean();
```

Instead of the echo, you put your include statement there.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into output buffering:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Though I suspect the design of your application can be improved so you don't need this.